# SSAS role based security - suppress entire hierarchy not entire dimension

Tags: sql-server, ssas

Main question: Is there a way in SSAS using role based security to suppress an **entire hierarchy** as opposed to an **entire dimension**?

We have a use case that would make it optimal to combine data *from multiple hierarchies into one dimension* and then suppress individual hierarchies based on the user's role.

Is there a way in SSAS using role based security to suppress an **entire hierarchy** as opposed to an **entire dimension**?

It seems as if SSAS considers dimensions and hierarchies to be synonymous, ie. it assumes that suppressing a dimension will suppress a hierarchy because there will never be more than one hierarchy per dimension.

We have tried suppressing all the individual attributes of a hierarchy but unfortunately when you do that the **name** of the hierarchy is still exposed in Excel. Does the name of a hierarchy , as opposed to its attributes, correspond to a member name or property that can also be suppressed?

can you set the  **AllowedMemberSet** property to **none** at the **hierarchy level** based on role? if you do that, will the name of the hierarchy still be exposed in Excel?

Can HideMemberIF suppress an **entire hierarchy** or only the **members** of an attribute hierarchy? Using this feature, similarly to the question above, does the name of a hierarchy , as opposed to its attributes, correspond to a member name that can also be suppressed?

**Note:**

We can't use perspectives because we have too many logical combinations of roles, which perspectives does not handle well.